# Georeferencing multiple images (100 or more) of same region in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I'm trying to georeference multiple satellite images of the same region over the course of a few years and get a separate output for each georeferenced image (a .tif file).

How can I achieve this in QGIS?

Is there a script that I can run?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, satellite imagery comes with geocoding. You can check this against a layer using the Quick Map Services plug in. Doing that will give you an idea of where you are. 
So, are you asking about clipping out a subset of the satellite images for your area of interest?
If that is the case, then you need to have a vector layer with your extent and use the GDAL tools under Extraction. There is an option there to run as a batch file.